# Functions with no side effect but with readonly access to state

Tags: functional-programming

Considering the common definition of pure functions:

> 1. the function return values are identical for identical arguments (no variation with local static variables, non-local variables, mutable reference arguments or input streams)
> 2. the function application has no side effects (no mutation of local static variables, non-local variables, mutable reference arguments or input/output streams).

What are the implications of using (only) impure functions that still have 2 but do not have 1, in the sense that they *can read* the current value of (some) immutable state, but *can not modify* (any) state ? Is such a pattern have a name and is useful or is it an anti pattern ?

An example can be using a global way to get a read only immutable version of a state, or passing as an argument a function that return the current immutable value of a state.

(Rationale - I have been trying to structure my (C#) code in a more functional way, using pure functions where possible (as static members of static classes).

It quickly became obvious how complex and tedious it is to pass state values to these pure functions even when they only need to read the value. I need to know the relevant state value at the point of calling and that often means passing it around through parts of the code which have no need to know it otherwise.

However if for example I initialize such static classes with an internal member function that can return the current immutable value of the state, other members can use it instead of having that value passed to them. And This pattern has greatly simplified my code where I used it. And it feels like I still get most of the benefits of isolating state *changes* etc)

Comment: It is missing #1 .. it _has #2. I fully understand that it is not pure anymore at least according to the above (wikipedia) definition. But it is still very different than the classic OOP unpure function that modifies some mutable (local) state

Comment: Sorry, read it opposite, let me re-read.

Comment: No, I still think my comment holds, it's just no longer pure functions. This is just OOP and what you're describing is just "properties". Not having side-effects is a good thing, easier to reason about the code. It should probably only matter if you *require* pure functions, either policy-wise or language-wise.

Comment: Yes I do not claim these are still pure functions. I am trying to understand the implications of them as this is still radically different than the classic OOP paradigm of members modifying some mutable  state

Answer (score 3):

An potentially impure operation without side effects fits the description of a Query in [Command-Query Separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation) (CQS) - a decade-old object-oriented design principle.

CQS explicitly distinguishes between operations with side effects (Commands) and operations that return data (Queries). According to that principle, a Query must not have a side effect.

On the other hand, CQS says nothing about determinism, so a Query is allowed to be non-deterministic.

In C#, a fundamental example of a Query is [DateTime.Now](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.datetime.now). This is essentially a method that takes no arguments - which is [equivalent with unit](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/01/15/unit-isomorphisms) as an input argument. Thus, we can think of `DateTime.Now` as a Query from unit to `DateTime`: `() -> DateTime`.

`DateTime.Now` is (in)famously non-deterministic, so it's clearly not a pure function. It is, however, a Query.

All pure functions are Queries, but not all Queries are pure functions.

CQS is a nice design principle, but it's not Functional Programming (FP). It's a move in the right direction, but you should attempt to have as few non-deterministic Queries as possible.

People often tend to focus on avoiding side-effects when learning FP, but it's just as important to avoid non-determinism.

Comment: thanks, I am not sure the pattern and example you give are fully relevant. Consider ie a Clojure function accepting an Atom that allows it to read the state. Sure not pure but that is a far cry from DateTime.Now or CQS

Comment: I'm only dimly aware of what a Clojure atom is. Is it like Haskell IORef or STRef?

Comment: @kofifus And how does that relate to the OP?